# NHibernate Fluent Sqlite force to use "Insert or Replace"

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

I need to force for NHibernate to not use typical `INSERT` statment, but sqlite's `INSERT OR REPLACE` statement

I know that it is possible when in `ClassMap<>` I'll use `SqlInsert("INSERT OR REPLACE...")`, but I have more then 100 entities and I don't wont to add it for every mapping class.

Has anyone an idea how to do it in another simple way?

Comment: Doesn't ISession.SaveOrUpdate does same thing..?

Comment: No, Insert Or Replace does not read the data before saving, so it is much faster then SaveOrUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT OR REPLACE needs the information which column is unique and decides if insert or replace should be used. There is no builtin mechanism for this in NHibernate because it is too special. The easiest way is to query before saving or handling the Duplicate key Exception (ISqlExceptionConverter helps here)